# Why is this video's duration incorrectly reported as 466 hours?

Tags: youtube

[This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LWS5xDEJsq8) video, while being in reality 13 minutes long, started being displayed with duration 466:16:28 in all other contexts, like in playlists, recommended etc. Why is that?

[image: Thumbnail showing 466:16:28]

Using the API, the duration is reported as P19DT10H16M28S, corresponding to the duration shown on thumbnails. What could be the source of this value?